# Two waypoints that trigger each other

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-waypoints

I have two divs that are stacked on top of each other in the sidebar.

```
<aside>
    <div class="waypoint">
        <p>Here is some text for the first div.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="waypoint absolutely-stuck">
        <p>Here is some text for the second div.</p>
    </div>
</aside>
```

I want to have the second div be initially placed way down the page, halfway through the content. So I have given it the following CSS:

```
.stuck {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.absolutely-stuck {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5000px;
}
```

I want to set up waypoints so that when the bottom of the first div reaches the top of the second div, the first div will stick where it lands, and the second div will begin scrolling down the page. If I scroll up, the opposite would happen: the second div would stick when it reaches the first div, and the first div would begin scrolling up. Here's what I have so far (that doesn't work):

```
var sticky = [];
$(".waypoint-ad").each(function(idx) {
    sticky[idx] = new Waypoint.Sticky({
        element: this,
        handler: function() {
            this.removeClass("absolutely-stuck");
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I think you have to use the jquery scroll event.